# Query all documents from MongoDb with Node

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

For the following **GET request**, I am trying to get the server to return all "Musician" documents, which I would then format on display on the musicians-all jade template page.

```
app.get("/musicians/all", function(req, res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    Musician.find(), function(err, data){
        if (err){
            res.render("error", {err: err});
        } else {
            console.log("here is the data: " + data);
            res.render("musicians-all", {
                musicians: data
            });

        }
    };
});
```

My models are setup with **Mongoose**:

```
module.exports = function(mongoose){

    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var MusicianSchema = new Schema({
        firstName: String,
        lastName: String,
        country: String,
        birthday: Date,
        instruments: [],
    });

    mongoose.model("Musician", MusicianSchema);

}
```

and I've setup an html form and a **post request** that properly submits the data.

```
app.post("/musicians/create", function(req, res){
    var firstName = req.body.firstName;
    var lastName = req.body.lastName;
    var country = req.body.country;
    var newMusician = new Musician;
    newMusician.firstName = firstName;
    newMusician.lastName = lastName;
    newMusician.country = country;
    newMusician.save(function(err, data){
        if (err){
            res.render("error", {err: err});
        }
        else {
            var id = data.id;
            res.redirect("/musicians/all");
            console.log(firstName + lastName + "from" + country); 
        }
    });
});
```

Though I can confirm that the documents are added to MongoDb when submitting the html form, I am unsure of how to access the documents I am looking for.

Comment: I think you're looking for `Musician.find`, not `Musician.findOne` if you want more than a single musician to show up.

Comment: And skip the ID parameter in that case.  Just `Musician.find({}, function(...`

Comment: Musician.find({},callbackfunction) gives you all documents, not findOne

Comment: Ah, whoops --- i forgot to get rid of that in this post. 

I am actually using Musician.find but it doesn't return anything

Comment: Musician.find({}, function(err, data){//blah blah});

Comment: thank you Jamsheed, I didn't have the callback function correctly specified